# How to get only changed records from SuiteTalk

Tags: netsuite

I am writing a program to find all records (e.g. customers) that have been updated and so I can write these changes to a legacy database.

My program sends a Search command to SuiteTalk with a (for example) CustomerSearchBasic object. The CustomerSearchBasic object defines a search for all records and compares their lastModifiedDate with the latest lastModifiedDate value it received when it last got results.

I have two options:

A) Ask for all records where the lastModifiedDate is not earlier than the latest lastModifiedDate it received when it last got results. This would mean that if two records were updated in the same second but last time I received just the first then this time I will receive both of them. This means I won't miss an update but I will usually receive at least one record whose update I have processed already.

B) Ask for all records where the lastModifiedDate is later than the latest lastModifiedDate it received when it last got results. This would mean that if two records were updated in the same second but last time I received just the first then this time I will receive neither of them. This means I can miss updates. I won't receive updates I have processed already.

So option A is safer but wasteful because I will usually download a record I don't want to process whereas option B is likely to miss some updates but doesn't cause unwanted results.

Is there a better option you can suggest?

Comment: Thanks, @cja, Since you are more experienced I want to know one thing if you created an invoice of a particular customer in Netsuite. customer balance will be changed but customer lastModifiedDate is not changing. how can I get all those customers their balance is updated.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to introduce a `synced` Check Box custom field for each record type that you'll be processing.

Initially, `synced` will be `F` for all of the records, indicating that they must be synchronized to the legacy database.

During each synchronization cycle, your program will do a search for all records where `synced` equals `F`. It will feed the resulting records into the legacy database. Once a record is successfully processed, your program will set the `synced` field to `T` in NetSuite.

Every time a record is changed in NetSuite, the `synced` field will be set to `F` again. This could be achieved manually (unchecking the box in the NetSuite form), through a client script, or through other means. This will include this record in the list of records to be synchronized during the next synchronization cycle of your program.

The downside to this method is that you have to keep the `synced` field up to date, especially when modifying records. The upside is that you'll never miss an updated record, and you'll never process an updated record twice (unless your program fails to set `synced` to `T`).

Another benefit of this approach is that your program can fail gracefully during a synchronization cycle, and pick up where it left off during the next cycle. This is because each item has its own `synced` flag.

---

**Better Solution**

Thinking about it, you could probably combine this method with your original method to remove the requirement of manually updating the `synced` flag when changing the records.

Instead of using a Check Box `synced` flag, use a Date/Time `last_synced` custom field. This `last_synced` custom field could store the date and time that this record was last processed in your program. Your search would then be modified to return all records that have a `last_synced` date and time that's earlier than the record's last updated date and time. Then, when your program processes a given record, it should update its `last_synced` field to the current date and time.

This hybrid solution has the advantages of both previous solutions and the disadvantages of neither.

Comment: The second idea is more manageable. However, it allows me to miss an update if a record is updated while I am processing it. I could modify that idea to set last_synced to the value of lastModifiedDate. This would mean I'd get all updates except in some cases where the record is updated twice in the same second

Comment: Setting it to the last modified date that you received when you queried the data would certainly alleviate issues with something updating while you're processing it. And you're right, this wouldn't help with same-second updates. Is there some sort of automated process that is updating these records so quickly? It seems unlikely for a record to change twice in the same second.

Comment: The system isn't even live yet - I'm planning. I like hole-less solutions.

Comment: I have found a fatal flaw with this solution: Updating the last synced field causes last modified date to be updated! Which then makes me think it's been updated again!

Comment: Hm, right. Well, `last_synced` would have to be updated to match the new last modified datetime (which would be a result of updating `last_synced`, argh). In the projects I'm involved in, I'm using the boolean `synced` field method. It is a bit tricky to make sure it's updated whenever the record is updated, but client and user scripts make it possible.